# bootstrap nav-tabs switch to another tab with tab-content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a normal bootstrap tab panel for switching blocks

I added a Go to List 2 button to the content for List 1

But how can I make it so that when I click on this button I switch to the List 2 tab?

I tried adding to the `a` tag id tab and all other attributes, but it doesn’t help

```css
li {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  display:none;
}

.nav {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav > li > a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a.active {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background: #A700FF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.info {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.go-to {
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list1" id="list1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list1" role="tab" aria-controls="list1" aria-selected="true" class="active">List 1</a> </li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list2" id="list2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list2" role="tab" aria-controls="list2" aria-selected="false" class="">List 2</a> </li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list3" id="list3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list3" role="tab" aria-controls="list3" aria-selected="false" class="">List 3</a> </li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list4" id="list4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list4" role="tab" aria-controls="list4" aria-selected="false" class="">List 4</a> </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="list1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list1-tab" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="info">List 1 info</div>
    <a href="#list2" class="go-to">Go to List 2</a>
  </div>
    <div id="list2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list2-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="info">List 2 info</div>
  </div>
    <div id="list3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list3-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="info">List 3 info</div>
  </div>
    <div id="list4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list4-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="info">List 4 info</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give the link a click handler, that invokes the `show` method. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I Added id="goToList2" id to your "Go to List 2" button, so you can select it with JavaScript/jQuery.
2. Used jQuery to trigger a click event on the List 2 tab when the button is clicked.

When the button is clicked, it triggers a click event on the List 2 tab, making it active and displaying its content.

Look at the snippet to see if correct.,

```css
li {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  display:none;
}

.nav {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav > li > a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a.active {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  background: #A700FF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.info {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.go-to {
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tab Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list1" id="list1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list1" role="tab" aria-controls="list1" aria-selected="true" class="active">List 1</a> </li>
        <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list2" id="list2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list2" role="tab" aria-controls="list2" aria-selected="false" class="">List 2</a> </li>
        <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list3" id="list3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list3" role="tab" aria-controls="list3" aria-selected="false" class="">List 3</a> </li>
        <li role="presentation"> <a href="#list4" id="list4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list4" role="tab" aria-controls="list4" aria-selected="false" class="">List 4</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="list1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list1-tab" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="info">List 1 info</div>
            <a href="#" class="go-to" id="goToList2">Go to List 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="list2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list2-tab" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="info">List 2 info</div>
        </div>
        <div id="list3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list3-tab" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="info">List 3 info</div>
        </div>
        <div id="list4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list4-tab" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="info">List 4 info</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // jQuery code to switch to List 2 when the button is clicked
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#goToList2").click(function () {
                $("#list2-tab").tab("show");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```